# Unable to attach or mount volumes : MountVolume.SetUp failed rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I've followed the steps & replicated the same from the official [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-persistent-storage/#) of AWS EKS to mount a volume with EFS. But, facing the below error.

```
Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[persistent-storage], unattached volumes=[persistent-storage kube-api-access-29fgm]: timed out waiting for the condition
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "efs-pv" : rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

This is the [link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/multiple_pods/specs/claim.yaml) for the yaml files. I've been trying for many days. Any help to find out the error is much appreciated!!

Comment: any update on this issue ?

Comment: No, I couldn't able to find out the issue still.

Comment: Anyone find a solution to this? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the security group associated with your EFS file system and worker nodes allows NFS traffic

Your AWS EFS Filesystem has security group. You need to make changes to security group to allow the pods to connect with EFS file system.

[Reference Link GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/issues/34#issuecomment-483810679)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the storageclass used to created PV was defined in default vpc network, while the pods was installed in different vpc.
The solution is to manually create stroagecalss by using parameter network, assign it to pod VPC, and recreate the pods.

The manifest sc-trial.yaml to create SC is:

kubectl apply -f ./sc-trial.yaml

```
allowVolumeExpansion: true
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    components.gke.io/component-name: filestorecsi
    components.gke.io/component-version: 0.11.6
    components.gke.io/layer: addon
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
    k8s-app: gcp-filestore-csi-driver
  name: standard-rwx-xxx
parameters:
  tier: standard
  network: gke-xxx-vpc
provisioner: filestore.csi.storage.gke.io
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```